Video is not playing when passing video source as a blob url on android edge
I am using html5 video player for playing video. I have the video hosted as a public video. I am downloading the video and then converting it into a blob and then using createObjectURL() method to get a blob url but it is not playing the video on android edge only. No error or warning in the console.
https://jsfiddle.net/h12kmvdq/
fetch(
    "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerMeltdowns.mp4" 
)
.then((videoResponse) => {
  videoResponse.blob().then((blobData) => {
    blobData.arrayBuffer().then((blobArray) => {
      const videoBlob = new Blob([blobArray], { type: "video/mp4" });
      const videoSrc = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
      console.log(videoSrc, 'video src');
      const videoElement = document.getElementById('video');
      videoElement.src = videoSrc;
      setTimeout(() => {
        videoElement.play();
      }, 200);
    });
   })
})l


I reproduced the issue you described on Android Edge, but when I tested it on Android Chrome, the video could play normally. And I then searched some documents and resources, but did not find any records or solutions for this issue. This should be a new issue. So, my only suggestion is that you should press "Shift+Alt+I" to submit feedback in Edge.
